# Linking multiple C source files

Tags: c, linker, gentoo, gcc4

I'm on gentoo linux with GCC 4.4.5 installed. I can compile and link such program without any errors using **gcc main.c -o main**, and the command **./main** returns result correctly.

```
[main.c] 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double c = ceil(2.5);
    printf("The ceil of 2.5 is %f\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I put the invokation of **ceil** into another source file, the problem occurs.

```
[calc.h]
#ifndef _CALC_H_
#define _CALC_H_
double myceil(double n);
#endif

[calc.c]
#include <math.h>
#include "calc.h"
double myceil(double n)
{
    return ceil(n);
}

[main1.c]
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc.h"
int main(void)
{
    double c = myceil(2.5);
    printf("The ceil of 2.5 is %f\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the command **gcc calc.c main1.c -o main1**, such error occurs:

```
/tmp/cc6GhJvZ.o: In function `myceil':
calc.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `ceil'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So why did the annoying error "undefined references" happen in the latter case? And I know the error could be eliminated by adding an library **-lm**, however, I just want to know why gcc will throw the error in the latter case.

Comment: This error does not show up in osx or in RHEL 6 ...

Comment: @Foo,recently I installed rhel-workstation-6.0-i386-dvd.iso on Vmware Workstation 7.0.0, but the error is still there.

Comment: ooh I was using the x64 server edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that GCC optimizes `ceil(2.5)` to a constant, whereas `ceil(n)` is not constant because `n` is not known when compiling `calc.c`, and it needs to reference the function.  You can confirm this by looking at the assembly output (`gcc -S`).

**Update:** Here's what gcc 4.2.1 on x86 gave me for something similar to your first example:

```
.LC1:
    .string "%f\n"
    // [snip]
main:
    // [snip]
    fldl    .LC0
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    printf
    // [snip]
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1074266112
```

Here we see `printf` being called with a `double` constant.

Now if I do something similar to your second example:

```
myceil:
    // [snip]
    fldl    -8(%ebp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    call    ceil
    // [snip]
```

Here we see `ceil` being referenced.

So yeah.  I'd say your call is being optimized to a constant in the one that works without `-lm`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use `gcc -S` concretely, or some tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: Example usage: `gcc -S foo.c`.  This will output a file called `foo.s`.  Of course, some knowledge of your platform's assembly language will also help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is exactly what you say. When I replace the `ceil(2.5)` with `ceil(x)` where the value of x is 2.5, the referencing error occurs just like my latter case.

Comment: Checking with -fno-builtin might be of interest if you're into that sort of thing (and hey, who isn't into that?).

Answer (score 2):

gcc has a list of [built-in functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and `ceil` is one of them. On my version of OSX, gcc uses the built-in `ceil` in both of your cases so `-lm` is not necessary. Apparently your Gentoo compiler behaves differently and only uses the built-in `ceil` in some cases. If you try compiling with `-fno-builtin` then you'll have to use `-lm` for both of your compilations.

Comment: Thanks @mu. When I use `gcc -fnobuilt-in main.c -o main`, the referencing error occurs. It seems that in my gentoo the built-in functions only accept the constant parameter, e.g. 2.5 in my former case.

Comment: @machinarium: That's cool, I figured it was optimized away too but I thought I'd mention the built-ins as they can cause some confusing behavior. Could be the multiple file issue as well or something in the compiler's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you first compile main.c to main.o and calc.c to calc.o, then link those? That's normally what I would expect (linking object files rather than trying to compile multiple C files on a single command line).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use the following commands `gcc -c calc.c` `gcc -c main1.c` and `gcc -o main1 calc.o main1.o`, but the same error still occurs.